# How can I disable GraphQL Api doc in nuwave lighthouse when I release the server

Tags: laravel-lighthouse

I'd like to disable the GraphQL API doc query entry(which lists the document of all my GraphQL
Apis) in lighthouse, but I'v not yet found any configuration for that. How can? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is called ["introspection"](https://graphql.org/learn/introspection/) in GraphQL lingo.

You can disable it in the [`config/lighthouse.php`](https://github.com/nuwave/lighthouse/blob/dd172cc1245bb871706ea332a1536c5455a5dd55/src/lighthouse.php#L196) config file.

You can find a section called `security` like this in there:

```php
    'security' => [
        'max_query_complexity' => \GraphQL\Validator\Rules\QueryComplexity::DISABLED,
        'max_query_depth' => \GraphQL\Validator\Rules\QueryDepth::DISABLED,
        'disable_introspection' => \GraphQL\Validator\Rules\DisableIntrospection::DISABLED,
    ],
```

Change the `DisableIntrospection` from `DISABLED` to `ENABLED`:

```
-       'disable_introspection' => \GraphQL\Validator\Rules\DisableIntrospection::DISABLED,
+       'disable_introspection' => \GraphQL\Validator\Rules\DisableIntrospection::ENABLED,
```

That will block the introspection query from working.